# UITableView Separator Style None in IB does not work

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I tried both changing the separator style to None in IB and .none in code.  In other tables that have a simple label in the row in other parts of my app, when I try to remove the separator style it works.  But for some reason, in this UITableView it does not and I'm not sure why.  Here is the screenshot from the simulator.

[image]

And here is a screenshot of the storyboard

[image]

In the storyboard, it's basically a UIView on the left with the initials, and then the three labels are embedded in two UIStackViews.  There's a bottom horizontal UIStackView for grade and school, and then a vertical UIStackView for name and the bottom stack view.  Do stack views prevent you from using separator style = none?

Comment: Try to set seperatorColor to ClearColor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
self.tableView.separatorColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

OR

```
self.tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
```

Comment: @SiddeshMhatre ClearColor works but not separator style.  Do you know why?  It seems like separator style none should be the correct way to do it and works on other UITableViews in my app but not this one.

Comment: @Crystal same problem faced by others also. Its a bug see https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/12387